# Add column to dataframe based on date column range

Tags: python, date, datetime, pandas, time-series

I have a `df` containing `n` `columns`. One of these is a `column` named `date` which contains values formatted as `mm-dd-yy`. Now I want to add a `column` `interval` to my `df`. This `column` should return the `year` contained in `date` but also if it's `H1` or `H2`. `H1` is half year one and should be all `date` values between `01-dd-yy` `06-dd-yy` and thus `H2` should be all `date` values between `07-dd-yy` and `12-dd-yy`.

This is an example of the data in `df['date']`:

```
0         01-27-16
1         02-27-16
2         03-27-16
3         04-27-16
4         05-27-16
5         06-27-16
6         07-27-16
7         08-24-16
8         09-24-16
9         10-16-15
...etc...
```

In `df` I want to add another column named `interval` containing:

```
    0         16H1
    1         16H1
    2         16H1
    3         16H1
    4         16H1
    5         16H1
    6         16H2
    7         16H2
    8         16H2
    9         15H2
    ...etc...
```

So I thought I'd create a `function` and then use `map`.

```
def is_in_range(x):
   if x['date'] >= '01-01-16'  x['date'] <= '06-31-16':
       print '16H1'
   elif x['date'] >= '07-01-16' and x['date'] <= '12-31-16':
       print '16H2'
   elif x['date'] >= '01-01-15' and x['date'] <= '06-31-15':
       print '15H1'
   elif x['date'] >= '07-01-15' and x['date'] <= '12-31-15':
       print '15H2'  
   ...etc...
```

I call the function like this:

```
df.groupby(df['date'].map(is_in_range))
```

Now this gives me:

> `TypeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

to begin with. I'm not sure why, but either way there surely must be a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`dt.quarter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.quarter.html) or [`dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.month.html).

First convert `int` year value to `str` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html), then select last `2` chars. Last use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with condition:

```
#first convert to datetime if not datetime
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

df['interval'] = df.date.astype(str).str[2:4] + np.where(df.date.dt.month < 7, 'H1','H2')
print (df)
        date interval
0 2016-01-27     16H1
1 2016-02-27     16H1
2 2016-03-27     16H1
3 2016-04-27     16H1
4 2016-05-27     16H1
5 2016-06-27     16H1
6 2016-07-27     16H2
7 2016-08-24     16H2
8 2016-09-24     16H2
9 2015-10-16     15H2
```

Or:

```
df['interval'] = df.date.astype(str).str[2:4] + np.where(df.date.dt.quarter < 3,'H1','H2')
print (df)
        date interval
0 2016-01-27     16H1
1 2016-02-27     16H1
2 2016-03-27     16H1
3 2016-04-27     16H1
4 2016-05-27     16H1
5 2016-06-27     16H1
6 2016-07-27     16H2
7 2016-08-24     16H2
8 2016-09-24     16H2
9 2015-10-16     15H2
```

`string` solution:

```
df['interval'] = df.date.str[6:] + np.where(df.date.str[:2].astype(int) < 7, 'H1','H2')
print (df)
       date interval
0  01-27-16     16H1
1  02-27-16     16H1
2  03-27-16     16H1
3  04-27-16     16H1
4  05-27-16     16H1
5  06-27-16     16H1
6  07-27-16     16H2
7  08-24-16     16H2
8  09-24-16     16H2
9  10-16-15     15H2
```

List comprehension solutions work if not **NaN**:

`string` column:

```
df['interval'] = [x[6:] + 'H1' if int(x[:2])< 7 else x[6:] + 'H2' for x in df['date']]
```

`datetime` column:

```
#first convert to datetime if not datetime
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

df['interval'] = [x[2:4] + 'H1' if int(x[5:7])< 7 else x[2:4] + 'H2' for x in df['date'].astype(str)]

print (df)
       date interval
0  01-27-16     16H1
1  02-27-16     16H1
2  03-27-16     16H1
3  04-27-16     16H1
4  05-27-16     16H1
5  06-27-16     16H1
6  07-27-16     16H2
7  08-24-16     16H2
8  09-24-16     16H2
9  10-16-15     15H2
```

Answer (score 1):

is the 'date' column a string?  you can't really compare strings like that

convert the last two elements in the string to an int

```
A = [x[6:]+'H1' if int(x[6:]+)< 7 else 'H2' for x in df['date'].values]
```

and finally

```
df['interval'] = A
```